# R user-defined function to group multiple variables

Tags: r, function, user-defined-functions

I have merged survey data for 3 consecutive years in a single dataframe. it turns out that the variable names are different for each survey (e.g. there are 3 times a 100 variables, instead of just 100 variables). I'm trying to create a function that allows me to input the variables that pertain to the same question. The function then observes which one contains information and returns a new variable that replaces the original 3 variables.

I tried to create the function below. Using 'coalesce' to select the observation and disregarding all that is NA.

```
df <- matrix(c(3, NA, NA, NA, 0.2, NA, NA, NA, 0.5),
              ncol = 3, nrow = 3,
              dimnames = list(NULL, c("a", "b", "c")))

special_function <-function(df, Name_new_variable, Name_a, Name_b, Name_c, na.rm= FALSE) {
  df$Name_new_variable <- coalesce(df$Name_a,
                          df$Name_b,
                          df$Name_c
  )
  df$Name_a <- NULL
  df$Name_b <- NULL
  df$Name_c <- NULL
}
```

The expectation is for the function above to look into the dataframe "df". Consider the name for the new variable "name_new_variable" and merge the 3 columns Name_a, Name_b, Name_c.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share sample data with `dput` for people to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with surveys, I suggest you to use dataframe instead matrix for your `df`. As you are using `dplyr` library, so you can try this code:

```
special_function <-function(df, Name_new_variable, Name_a, Name_b, Name_c) {
  df <- as.data.frame(df) %>% select(Name_a, Name_b, Name_c)
  df[, Name_new_variable]= coalesce(df[, Name_a], df[, Name_b], df[, Name_c])
  df <- df %>% select(-c(Name_a, Name_b, Name_c)) 
  return(df)
}

special_function(df, "NewVariableName", "a", "b", "c")
```

The output:

```
> special_function(df, "NewVariableName", "a", "b", "c")
  NewVariableName
1             3.0
2             0.2
3             0.5
```